# "Access is Denied" when enabling auditing rules for Active Directory schema changes in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl

Not sure what I am doing wrong, but when I try to enable auditing rules for the schema I get an "access is denied" message. This is my powershell code

```
Import-Module activedirectory
set-location ad:
$everyone = [Security.Principal.NTAccount]"Everyone"
$none = [system.guid]"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

$schemaPath = (Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext

#schema
$ACLs = get-acl "AD:\$schemaPath" -audit
$newRule = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAuditRule($everyone,"CreateChild, DeleteChild, WriteProperty, ExtendedRight, Delete, WriteDacl","Success",$none,"All")
$ACLs.AddAuditRule($newRule)
$ACLs | set-acl
```

This is my error message

```
set-acl : Access is denied
At line:12 char:9
+ $ACLs | set-acl
+         ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (CN=Schema,CN=Co...eng,DC=domainname,DC=.yada:String) [Set-Acl], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ADProvider:SetSecurityDescriptor:AccessDenied,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

I've tried running this code as Domain Admin as well as Enterprise admin and it still gives me the access is denied message. I've also tried running this on the schema master and it always fails.

If I do the changes manually via 'ADSI Edit' everything works as expected.

I've confirmed that I'm running this command as Enterprise Admins

```
([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.NTAccount] "Enterprise Admins")
True
```

Comment: If you are running directly on a domain controller (usually not recommended), then you have to run your PowerShell session elevated.

Comment: I've tried from an elevated sessions and I still get access is denied

Comment: Can't reproduce. Evidently you don't have the permissions you think you have.

Comment: Since you're modifying the schema, you may have to use an account that has Schema Admin authority.

Comment: I dont understand how its working for you, I'm running this as enterprise admin

Comment: Yes, modifying schema requires membership in `Schema Admins`.

Answer (score 0):

The PDC I was running the command on was corrupt. Running the command on a different DC works ....

Comment: There's no PDC in an AD domain; only a PDC Emulator role.

Comment: Did you just assume my NT version :D

Answer (score 0):

You should run it under Schema Admin (it does not belong to Enterprise or Domain admin groups):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579255(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_SchemaAdmins